# How to add close button in SweetAlert pop up

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sweetalert, sweetalert2

I have used the SweetAlert library for displaying a pop up in my application. This is my code

```
swal({
    title: "Are you sure?",
    text: "Test message?",
    type: "info",
    showCancelButton: true,
    focusConfirm: false,
    confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
    confirmButtonText: "Yes",
    cancelButtonText: "No"
}, function (isConfirm) {})
```

I need to add a close button in top right corner. Based on documentation, the close button available only for the SweetAlert2 library.

Is it possible to add close button in the SweetAlert1 library?

Comment: It seems you use AngularJS. Why not use **ngSweetAlert** with? https://github.com/oitozero/ngSweetAlert

Comment: i already used sweetalert in my application. i cant use any other libraries

Comment: There's a cancel button also, which can be also used to close popup

Answer (score 12):

```
swal({
title: "Are you sure?",
text: "Test message?",
type: "info",
showCancelButton: true,
focusConfirm: false,
confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
confirmButtonText: "Yes",
cancelButtonText: "No",
showCloseButton: true,
```

Just add `showCloseButton: true` and this will show the close X icon in the top right corner of the pop up.

Source: See the "Custom HTML description and buttons with ARIA labels" example on [SweetAlerts2 Docs](https://sweetalert2.github.io/)

Note it is not available in SweetAlert1 library which is now deprecated, I would suggest using SweetAlert2.

Answer (score 10):

You can define a `mySwal` wrapper that checks for a `showCloseButton` param.

Here's an example for v2.1.0 of the original SweetAlert library:

```js
mySwal = function() {
  swal(arguments[0]);
  if (arguments[0].showCloseButton) {
    closeButton = document.createElement('button');
    closeButton.className = 'swal2-close';
    closeButton.onclick = function() { swal.close(); };
    closeButton.textContent = '×';
    modal = document.querySelector('.swal-modal');
    modal.appendChild(closeButton);
  }
}

mySwal({
  title: "Are you sure?",
  text: "Test message?",
  icon: "info", /* type: "info", */
  buttons: [
    "No", /* showCancelButton: true, cancelButtonText: "No", */
    "Yes" /* confirmButtonText: "Yes", */
  ],
  focusConfirm: false,
  showCloseButton: true
});
```

```css
.swal-button--confirm {
  background-color: #dd6b55; /* confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55", */
}

.swal-modal .swal2-close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 1.2em;
  height: 1.2em;
  transition: color 0.1s ease-out;
  border: none;
  background: transparent;
  color: #cccccc;
  font-family: serif;
  font-size: 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.swal-modal .swal2-close:hover {
  color: #f27474;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/2.1.0/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
```